# AWS Android Cognito SDK returns "Incorrect username or password"

Tags: amazon-web-services, basic-authentication, aws-amplify

I am using the AWS Cognito userpool for authentication. It worked well when I logged in from an emulator but when I tried it using my device, the following `Exception` occurred:

```
2020-04-15 12:07:02.596 14963-15045/com.example.aws_integration E/AWS: Sign-in error
    com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentityprovider.model.NotAuthorizedException: Incorrect username or password. (Service: AmazonCognitoIdentityProvider; Status Code: 400; Error Code: NotAuthorizedException; Request ID: d524ec86-b6f6-44f6-8bb5-90a622d33136)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:730)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:405)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:212)
        at com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentityprovider.AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient.invoke(AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient.java:6319)
        at com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentityprovider.AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient.respondToAuthChallenge(AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient.java:4959)
        at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognitoidentityprovider.CognitoUser.respondToChallenge(CognitoUser.java:2408)
        at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognitoidentityprovider.CognitoUser$24.run(CognitoUser.java:2480)
        at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognitoidentityprovider.continuations.AuthenticationContinuation.continueTask(AuthenticationContinuation.java:124)
        at com.amazonaws.mobile.client.AWSMobileClient$6$1.getAuthenticationDetails(AWSMobileClient.java:1185)
        at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognitoidentityprovider.CognitoUser.getSession(CognitoUser.java:778)
        at com.amazonaws.mobile.client.AWSMobileClient$6.run(AWSMobileClient.java:1145)
        at com.amazonaws.mobile.client.internal.InternalCallback$1.run(InternalCallback.java:101)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

I am entering the right credentials. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: try using the higher-level wrapper in AWS Amplify. https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/getting-started/q/platform/android . Also, can you update this question to include the code you're using for sign-in?